# Related Rates Cylinder - Increasing volume and calculating the rate that the height increases

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The question reads "Consider a circular cylinder of radius 1m and height 6m. We are filling the cylinder with oil at a rate of  $0.5  m^3 s^{-1}$. Assume the cylinder is sitting on its base. How quickly is the height changing when the liquid fills a quarter of the container?"

My attempt at the solution:

$V = \pi r^2h$

$\frac{dV}{dt} = \pi 1^2 \frac{dh}{dt}$

Substituting $0.5m^3s^{-1}$ for $\frac{dV}{dt}$

$0.5 = \pi \frac{dh}{dt}$

$\frac{dh}{dt} = \frac{0.5}{\pi}$

So I've arrived at a value for the rate of the increase of height, but I haven't used the fact that the question states that "the liquid fills a quarter of the container"

I'm not sure how to proceed from here to continue with the question.

Comment: I believe the quarter of the container part is simply extra information to confuse you and is unnecessary to solve the problem since the rate of fill is constant. The amount filled would only be necessary if the rate of fill varied with time as a way to determine how long it had been filling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have found that

$$h'(t) = \frac 1{2 \pi}$$

There's no $t$ on the right hand side, which means that $\frac 1{2 \pi}$ is the change in height regardless of the value $t$. So even if we call the time at which the liquid fills a quarter of the container $t_0^*$, we will still get $h'(t_0^*) = \boxed{\frac 1{2 \pi}}$.

---

*Extra credit: if we wanted to find $t_0^*$, what equation would we need to solve?